# Trying to do an http call to a remote URL

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to do a remote call in my node.js application to an external URL, then parse that request and perform an action based on the return. I'm using express and mysql.

I was able to get the remote URL content, however, I'm having some kind of race condition where my output is always changing and is not reliable. I tried to use async/await but wasn't able to.

This is the function called to run the app:

```
function lista(servidores) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var sql = ' SELECT sv.id as svid, sv.ip as svip'+
                  ' FROM servidores sv'     
        dbconfig.conexao.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
                Promise.all(
                result.map(row => {
                  var ipsv = row.svip;
                  var urlprobe = 'http://201.182.96.14:8000/PING/' + ipsv;
                  fetch(urlprobe, {
                        method: 'get',
                        headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
                        },})
                    .then(
                        response => response.json(),
                        error => console.log('Ocorreu um erro', error)
                    )
                    .then(
                        json => console.log(json),
                    )
                })
              ).then(result => result);  
        return resolve();
        });
    })           
}
```

When all these functions are called, everything works ok until the monitora() function. The output is random based on which fetch answers faster, and therefore the result is not reliable. The ideal is that 
 monitora() performs each fetch separetely and then process the if's based on each one of the results.

@edit: I edited the code and made the fetch directly on the main function, however I'm still receiving inconsistent results, like if there was some sort of caching somewhere.

Comment: You don't seem to await the `monitora` in `probes`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla could you please instruct as to how would I do this?

Comment: I edited my code do to all the calls in one function, but still I'm receiving wrong results. It's like there's some sort of caching of some kind, I have to hit the endpoint multiple times to get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly but you can try using `Promise.all()` function to wait for all fetch requests to finish, before taking an action.

```
Promise.all(
  result.map(row => {
    var urlMon = 'http://' + row.pip + ':8000/PING/' + ipsv;
    monitora(urlMon, idsv);
  })
).then(result => result /*Do something */);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using this code doesn't wait also. I'm priting the result of this promise and it's returning undefined, and then a couple seconds later the return show up on the console.